# VS code truncates variables when debugging

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.32 and when I try to debug my python script, variables that I am tracking in the debugging window are truncated. Even when I try to copy the value and paste it somewhere else, it also appears truncated. Here is an example.

```
[{u'info': {...}, u'hash': u'-853332357820028644'}, 
{u'info': {...}, u'hash': u'8548968643762198578'}, 
{u'info': {...}, u'hash': u'-700728790404992596'}, 
{u'info': {...}, u'hash': u'2290966790966655539'}, 
{u'info': {...}, u'hash': u'-1562196351113992652'}, 
{u'info': {...}, u'hash': u'-6557455005686897763'}, 
{u'info': {...}, u'hash': u''}]
```

Is there a setting that I am missing that will allow me to see the full value?

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround from the Debug Console you could dump the variable to a file whilst debugging and execute

```
with open("thisfilehere.txt", "w") as f: # press SHIFT+ENTER
    f.write(str(yourvariable))
```

then open file and copy text

Answer (score 0):

There's no setting; the value is just too big to show. If you would like a way to somehow show everything regardless of size then feel free to file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.