# VS Code with Xdebug does not show full PHP variable value

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using a step debugger to debug my code.

I have a json string stored in `$x` and I need to copy the value.
But the value is not showing completly, it just shows half of it, so I can't copy it.

[image]

Is there a way to solve it without a workaround e.g. write the value into a file?

---

Tested with VSC 1.68.1

Comment: Did you try to right-click on the variable and choose "Copy value"?

Comment: This is probably the number one gripe I have for VS Code.  Maybe things have changed, or I just failed to find a way.  Maybe see if these posts help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756331/how-to-show-the-entire-value-in-vscode-debug-mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764639/how-to-stop-vs-code-from-truncating-python-data-in-the-console https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223462/vs-code-truncates-variables-when-debugging

Comment: @DorinBotan I actually think if you do that, it will copy up to the `...` part - very annoying.

Comment: @DorinBotan, yes, it does copy half of the value.

Comment: @Black This seems Xdebug related then. Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291170/show-long-strings-in-vs-code-when-working-with-php-xdebug

Comment: @DorinBotan, thank you, that solved it! I also had stop the debugger and start it again to make it load the change I made in the launch.json!

Comment: @DorinBotan pls add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382935/4684797).

Just add this:

```
        "xdebugSettings": {
            "max_children": 128,
            "max_data": -1,
            "max_depth": 3
        },
```

to your .vscode/launch.json